# Why can I not change from XFile to File?

Tags: flutter, dart

I wish to display image taken from the Camera.
My imports are -

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:file/file.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
```

The code block with the issue

```
class _CollectdataState extends State<Collectdata> {
  XFile imageFile;
  _getFromCamera() async {
    XFile? pickedFile = await ImagePicker().pickImage(
      source: ImageSource.camera,
      maxWidth: 1800,
      maxHeight: 1800,
    );
    if (pickedFile != null) {
       File imageFile = File(pickedFile.path);

    }
  }
```

The error here was

1.File needs 2 parameters- I am unsure on what the second parameter is.

Then I changed something around idr what exactly but the imports if I remember correctly and this was the new error-

2. File is not a function

I need to change it to a File inorder to upload on Firebase and show the picture using image.file()
Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: I directly copied, pasted, and tested your code, it's working! Please share the error log.

Comment: @blackkara  lib/pages/collect_data.dart:28:26: Error: The class 'File' is abstract and can't be instantiated.
        File imageFile = File(pickedFile.path); I must mention i changed XFile imageFile to File? imageFile

Comment: Kushik Chandru's answer worked!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove

```
import 'dart:html';
```

If this package isn't used.
Both html and dart:io provide File. The error that you mentioned was for File from html.